# Disclosure of info

Tags: tournament

If player a inadvertently sees player B's hand as they look at their cards is either player obligated by rule to disclose this info to other players at the table?

Answer (score 2):

They are not obligated to tell other players about the information that they have, but it is the right thing to do. They can keep it to themselves, but it would be kind of scummy. Most players will announce if they see a card so that everyone has the same information because that is what they would want other players to do if their card was exposed.